# Relevant method to include for collections.Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, counter

Apologies if this is a repeat on the site (I searched around but couldn't find an answer). Say I have a `Person` class implemented in Python with name and age parameters, like `Person('Bob', 25)`. Say I then create a list of `Person` objects and I want to know how many of each instance there are; for example, I might have `[Person('Bob', 25), Person('Sally', 40'), Person('Bob', 25), Person('Sarah', 30)]`. So there are two instances of `Person('Bob', 25)` and 1 instance for the remainder; if were to run collections.Counter on this list of objects, it would return this correctly.

My question is: what exactly does collections.Counter look for in a data structure such that the count is correct? I have a more complicated (but hashable) class, and collections.Counter isn't counting the number of elements correctly. I'm sure this is because I just have some method missing from the definition, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: The basic methods you need are `__hash__()` and `__eq__()`, with the requirement that any two objects that compare equal must return the same hash.

Comment: @jasonharper It was indeed including the __eq__() method that solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a == b` then `hash(a) == hash(b)`

You need to implement [`__`hash`__`()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`__`eq`__`()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)